# Group Indicator is not coming in the right side of Expandable List view

Tags: android

Group Indicator is  not coming in the right side of Expandable List view  in android Even if I have applied all the  given solution  for it but its not working

Comment: post your code and layout

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file

ExpandableListView

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

In adapter

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (isExpanded) {
    groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
} else {
    groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
     }
}
```

You have to use custom image to achieve this.